# Subset of Power Set of Naturals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Q: Give a set S such that $S \subseteq P(\mathbb{N})$ and |S|=5.

My answer: S = $\{${1},{2},{3},{4},{5}$\}$.

Is this valid? It seems piddly, but perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: The point of the question is to see if you understand the definitions of power set and subset and can apply them.  If you do understand them it is not supposed to be a difficult question.  Good work.

Comment: How would this change if we needed S ∈ P(N) with cardinality five? Would the set S still hold? @RossMillikan

Comment: No, your $S$ is not an element of $P(\Bbb N)$.  If you take off the inner braces you get an element of $P(\Bbb N)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is valid. $S$ is a subset of the power set of $\mathbb{N}$, so it is made up of sets (to be more precise, subsets of $\mathbb{N}$). Also, $S$ has 5 elements. The set you found has both of these properties.